# Org Tags mess up on fast completion

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, tags

In my `init.el` I have the following lines:

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (set (make-local-variable 'org-complete-tags-always-offer-all-agenda-tags)
                  t)))
```

In my org file, I have more than a hundred tags and have the following line at the very top:

```
#+TAGS: { Incoming(i) Outgoing(o) }
```

Now, when I `C-c c t` to add a new task and to `C-c C-q` to add tags, I want ONLY i and o to be shown as options. But instead, it shows me multiple tags with random keys assigned to them!

How do I tell org mode to ONLY show EXPLICITLY defined short-cut keys?